# why assigning a command line argument to a dynamically allocated array shows error

Tags: c, free

I am learning C and in a specific code ,I have assigned a command line argument to a character array whose memory
is allocated dynamically

```
       char *ptr;
       ptr=(char *)malloc(500*sizeof(char));
       ptr=argv[argc-2];
```

and after completing the code and freeing the memory

```
free(ptr);
```

I am getting an error

```
*** Error in `./a': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff00c0c604 ***
```

can any one help me where is my mistake

Comment: Your third line is a leak because in reassigning `ptr`, you throw away the handle to the memory you just allocated.

Comment: then is there any way to assign the command line argument to the array,thank you

Comment: Use `strcpy` to copy a string.

Comment: You are not putting the data pointed by the `argv[argc-2]` to your allocated array, you are just making your pointer point to the same block of memory as `argv[argc-2]`. Hence you are `free`ing a memory that doesn't belong to you. Use [strcpy](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) to copy the contents to your array. Also why are you dynamically allocating it to begin with?

Comment: `ptr = malloc(...); /* nah, nevermind, forget that */ ptr = argv[...];`

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1` and should be omitted. Simply `ptr=malloc(500);` In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)   Validate EVERY allocation, e.g. `if (ptr == NULL) { /* handle error */ }` Shorthand of `if (!ptr) { ...` is equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few misconceptions.

"I have assigned a command line argument to a character array".
`ptr=argv[argc-2];`
No you did not. You assigned the value of a pointer (to a character sequence from commandline arguments) to a pointer variable (losing the pointer to malloced memory which was previously stored there).

"after completing the code [...] freeing the memory"

`free(ptr);`

Not really, what you are doing is calling `free()` on a pointer which was NOT previously malloced (because of having lost it with previous mistake).

That is the explanation of what happens.
The comment by Retired Ninja hints at a solution, though I recommend to use `strncpy()` instead, to copy the commandline argument to the memory you have allocated. It keeps the pointer to allocated memory (instead of overwriting it) and that in turn allows to free it later.